# Ada language understanding: a child of a renamed package

Tags: syntax, ada

Let's have, say, package with child package(s):

```
-- a.ads
package A is
end A;

-- a-b.ads
package A.B is
end A.B;
```

Now I want to rename `A` to `X`:

```
-- x.ads
package X renames A;
```

The question one is: will a child package `A.B` be accessible as being renamed to `X.B` too?

```
-- test.adb
with X.B; -- Is it ok? Why?
...
```

The question two is: is it legal to make a child of a renamed package, say `X.C`?

It looks like in GNAT it is renamed, but is it standard behaviour? Some reading of a 2005 and 2012 LRM doesn't clear that for me. Can you please point me to sections in LRM answering my questions?

Comment: Renaming the child package sounds like a gift from the IDE and not the language. It certainly would not happen if one uses the Vim editor.

Comment: @JimRogers I'm not about editing of a source code but about Ada's ```renames``` clause. It makes package (variable, subprogram) accessible under defferent name. And I do not use IDE, I use nano and mc, pretty minimalistic.

Comment: I found answer to my second question: Ada 2012 LRM 10.1.1 15/2 explicitly forbids this...